# How to validate DateTime for a leap year

Tags: c#, datetime, leap-year

I'm working with C# and I'm trying to find whether the given date and month is valid for a leap year. This is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The following program is to find whether the Date and Month is Valid for an LEAP YEAR");
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the Date");
    int date = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());  //User values for date and month
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the Month");
    int month = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
    {
        if (month == 2 && date < 30)                 //Determination of month and date of leap year using If-Else
            Console.WriteLine("Your input is valid");
        else if ((month == 1 || month == 3 || month == 5 || month == 7 || month == 8 || month == 10 || month == 12) && date < 32)
            Console.WriteLine("Your inpput valid1");
        else if (( month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11 ) && date < 31)
            Console.WriteLine("Your inpput valid2");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Your input INvalid");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

My question is, can I use `DateTime` for this program or is this a better way? Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest taking the input as a `string` and then using the [`DateTime.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) method. `DateTime.TryParse` accepts a `string` and an `out DateTime` ([out keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx)), and returns `true` if the string input was both correctly parsed and is a valid `DateTime`, and `false` otherwise.

From the documentation:

> If s is the string representation of a leap day in a leap year in the current calendar, the method parses s successfully. If s is the string representation of a leap day in a non-leap year in the current culture's current calendar, the parse operation fails and the method returns false.

Usage example:

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter a date.");

string dateString = Console.ReadLine();
DateTime dateValue;

if (DateTime.TryParse(dateString, out dateValue))
{
    // Hooray, your input was recognized as having a valid date format,
    // and is a valid date! dateValue now contains the parsed date
    // as a DateTime.
    Console.WriteLine("You have entered a valid date!");
}
else
{
    // Aww, the date was invalid.
    Console.WriteLine("The provided date could not be parsed.");
}
```

Comment: Can I check the month also in the above mentioned way?

Comment: Yes, this will check the entire date. For example, the user might input 1/23/2016 or 1-23-2016. The `TryParse` method even recognizes input such as 23 January 2016 or Sat, 23 Jan 2016.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`DateTime.DaysInMonth`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.daysinmonth(v=vs.110).aspx) with a year that is a known leap year like 2016.

```
if (month >= 1 && month <= 12 && date >= 1 && date <= DateTime.DaysInMonth(2016, month))
    Console.WriteLine("Your input is valid");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Your input is invalid");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a known leap year for the year part e.g. 2000 and append the month and day and year to form a string like mm-dd-2000 where `mm` and `dd` are the user entered values. Then use the [DateTime.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1(v=vs.110).aspx) method which returns true if the date is valid.

Answer (score 1):

If you're working from separate parts, then just:

```
try
{
    new DateTime(year, month, day);
}
catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
{
    // it's not valid
}
```

Though if you prefer not to rely on exceptions, then go with juharr's answer, using `DateTime.DaysInMonth`.